# Making an image (ie. image-mode) auto reload changes from disk

Tags: image-mode, auto-revert-mode

I have an image generated by plantuml which I open in an Image mode buffer. I want to use Auto-Revert mode so it auto-refreshes, but it doesn't seem to work on Image mode buffers for some reason. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 9):

As someone who just had this problem, I found another solution: `auto-image-file-mode`. What it does is automatically make sure the file is in image mode instead of binary, so enable both that and `auto-revert-mode` and everything works as expected. Emacs 24.4.1

Source: http://osdir.com/ml/bug-gnu-emacs-gnu/2014-01/msg01061.html

Answer (score 4):

You don't provide much information about what you are doing or what you are seeing. Try to give a step-by-step recipe, preferably starting from `emacs -Q`, and say what you expect versus what you see.

Does *manually reverting* the buffer work (`M-x revert-buffer`, after setting the current buffer to the image buffer)? If so, then investigate what is different about auto-reversion.

Are you using `global-auto-revert-mode`?  If not, is your image buffer on `auto-revert-buffer-list`? If not, then that would explain things: `auto-revert-mode` adds the current buffer to that list, and `auto-revert-buffers` reverts buffers that are on that list.

I'm no expert on `image-mode`, but searching for `revert` in `image-mode.el` I see function `image-after-revert-hook`. If it were I, I might start by `M-x debug-on-entry image-after-revert-hook` (after loading `image-mode.el`, not `image-mode.elc`), and then stepping through the debugger (e.g., using `d`).

(A wild guess tells me that that function is not even called, and that the image buffer is not a candidate for reverting. See above.  Maybe try `global-auto-revert-mode`, to start with.)

Answer (score 3):

I tried opening a png in emacs, enabling `auto-revert-mode` and then from a shell, copying another image over it and then replacing that file with a copy of the original png.

What I found is that the file is sometimes updated to the new files binary contents, but not the rendered content. If it opens the binary content, try using <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to convert it to an image.

After doing that conversion at least once, it starts auto-reverting as I would expect by keeping it an image.

Note: I tried this with Emacs 25.1, so it may be a new feature. What version are you using?

Comment: 24.3 - time to update! I used to stay on the source head or near it, but the release version is pretty good these days.